# Edit Product with images using React-Dropzone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dropzone

When creating a product I use React-Dropzone but when editing I intend to use it in the same way. I would like that when editing the product, the images that are already uploaded to the product are displayed under React-Dropzone so that the user can delete them all, or just one, etc.

This code works fine when uploading images, but when I pass the array with the images that already have the product in the database at the time of editing, it shows me the empty image preview:

```
import React from 'react';
import {useDropzone} from 'react-dropzone'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const DragAndDrop = ({files, setFiles, setDropError }) => {

  console.log(files); //Array of images that the product already has in the database

  const onDropRejected = () => {
    setDropError('Imágenes con tamaño Máximo de 1MB')
    setTimeout(() => {
      setDropError('')
    }, 3000)
  }

  const {
    acceptedFiles,
    fileRejections,
    getRootProps,
    getInputProps
  } = useDropzone({  
    accept: {
      'image/jpeg': [],
      'image/jpg': [],
      'image/png': []
    },  
    maxFiles:3,
    maxSize:1000000,
    onDropRejected,
    onDropAccepted: acceptedFiles => {
      console.log(acceptedFiles);
      if (files.length<1){
          setFiles(acceptedFiles.map(file =>
          Object.assign(file, {
            preview: URL.createObjectURL(file)
          }))); 
      } else {
        setFiles(files.map(file => 
          Object.assign(file, {
            preview: URL.createObjectURL(file) //Here I try to pass the images to create the preview but the images are not shown
          }))); 
      }
    }
  })

...
```

How can I accomplish this task? Thank you.

Comment: hi, did you find the answer to this question? I have the same problem

Comment: @MelikeKozan yes, I posted it as an answer, sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
import React from 'react';
import {useDropzone} from 'react-dropzone'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const DragAndDrop = ({files, setFiles, setDropError, totalFiles }) => {

  //const [files, setFiles] = useState([])


  const onDropRejected = () => {
    setDropError('Hasta 3 imágenes. máximo 2 MB')
    setTimeout(() => {
      setDropError('')
    }, 3000)
  }

  const {
    acceptedFiles,
    fileRejections,
    getRootProps,
    getInputProps
  } = useDropzone({  
    accept: {
      'image/jpeg': [],
      'image/jpg': [],
      'image/png': []
    },  
    maxFiles:3,
    maxSize:2000000,
    onDropRejected,
    onDropAccepted: acceptedFiles => {
     setFiles(acceptedFiles.map(file => 
      Object.assign(file, {
        preview: URL.createObjectURL(file)
      }))); 
    }
  })

  const removeFile = file => () => {
    const newFiles = [...files]
    newFiles.splice(newFiles.indexOf(file), 1)
    setFiles(newFiles)
  }

  const removeAll = () => {
    setFiles([])
  }

  const thumbs = files.map(file => (

      <div key={file.name}>
        <button onClick={removeFile(file)} className="text-center hover:bg-blue-200 absolute rounded">
          <span className='p-2 text-center text-lg'>x</span>
        </button>
        <div className='w-32'>
          <img
            src={file.preview}
            // Revoke data uri after image is loaded
            onLoad={() => { URL.revokeObjectURL(file.preview) }}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
  ))

  useEffect(() => {
    // Make sure to revoke the data uris to avoid memory leaks, will run on unmount
    return () => files.forEach(file => URL.revokeObjectURL(file.preview));
  }, []);

  const acceptedFileItems = acceptedFiles.map(file => (
    <li key={file.path}>
      {file.path} - {file.size} bytes
    </li>
  ));

  const fileRejectionItems = fileRejections.map(({ file, errors  }) => { 
   return (
     <li key={file.path}>
          {file.path} - {file.size} bytes
          <ul>
            {errors.map(e => <li key={e.code}>{e.message}</li>)}
         </ul>
     </li>
   ) 
  });
  

  return (
    <section className={`container mt-6`}>
      <div {...getRootProps({ className: 'dropzone' })} 
      className={`flex flex-col w-full border-2 border-cyan-600 border-dashed p-4 cursor-pointer  ${ files.length === 3 || totalFiles && totalFiles.length === 3  && 'pointer-events-none'  }`}>
        <input {...getInputProps()} />
        {
          files.length === 3 || totalFiles && totalFiles.length === 3 ? (
            <div className='flex justify-center'>
              <div className=' text-center gap-2 mb-2'>
                <p>Deshabilitado - Máximo 3 imágenes</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div className='text-center gap-2 mb-2'>
              <p>Arrastra y suelta imágenes o selecciona dando click</p>
              <em className='text-xs'>(Máximo 3 imágenes, .jpg, .png)</em>
            </div>
          )
        }
      </div>
      <aside className='text-xs mt-4'>
      {files.length === 3 && <div>{files.length}</div>}
    {/*     <h4>Archivos Correctos</h4>
        <ul>{acceptedFileItems}</ul>
        <h4>Archivos con error</h4>
        <ul>{fileRejectionItems}</ul> */}
        <div className="flex gap-4 justify-center">
          {thumbs}
        </div>
      </aside>
      {files.length > 0 && <button onClick={removeAll} className="btn btn-xs text-xs mt-4 btn-ghost">Eliminar</button>}
    </section>
  );
}

export default DragAndDrop
```